Efficiently finding the sumset of two arithmetic sequences
I want to find the sumset $A + B = \{a + b \ | \ a \in A, \ b \in B\}$ of the sets $A$ and $B$ where
$A = \{a_i \ | \ a_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \ a_{i+1} = a_i + 1, \ i = 0,...,N-1\}$
and
$B = \{b_j \ | \ b_0 = ks, \ b_{j+1} = b_j + s$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}, \ 0 < s < 1, \ j = 0,...,M-1\}$
$A$ and $B$ will be finite but potentially large so I wonder if anyone knows of some efficient (as in more efficient than stepping through each element of B for each element of A) algorithm for finding this set?
PS: I'm not sure this is a question fitting math stackExchange but I figure it has to do with combinatorics?

How is (for example) $~A~$ a set with only a finite number of elements?  The set $~{ ~a_0, ~a_0+1, ~a_0 + 2, ~\cdots ~}~$ seems to me to be a set with an infinite number of elements.  Is there some unspecified upper bound on the elements in $~A~?~$  If so, this should be made crystal clear by you, by editing your posted question.  Please do not respond with a comment.  Clarifications belong directly in the posted question.

Similarly, how is $~B~$ a set with only a finite number of elements?

Edited, hopefully it clarifies. These sets show up in a real application where they are finite.

Yes, these are good clarifications.
